# iOS branch.io SDK network failures

Tags: branch.io

NewRelic is reporting various network failures happening often from calls into various branch.io urls from the SDK.  Should we be concerned with what we see here?  This is pretty constant and is a lot of errors for a 24 hour period.  Are we losing important data?

[image]

Comment: Can you share the corresponding SDK code snippets you are using? Most of these errors suggest no/low internet connectivity. If you are using an old SDK version, we'd suggest updating to a more recent one.

Comment: we are on the latest SDK

Comment: We are calling the following SDK methods: handlePushNotification, continueUserActivity, openUrl, setIdentity, and setRequestMetadataKey

Comment: Do you see these error messages while testing as well? Any steps to reproduce would be helpful. You can reach out to support@branch.io so that we can investigate this deeper.